# Can spiritual weapon fly?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can I cast spiritual weapon into the air and hit a flying creature? Also, can I summon a spiritual weapon on the ground and have it go into the air to attack a creature that is flying or elevated somehow?

It says you create a floating weapon so I was unsure if it could float up to a creature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since it doesn't specify (beyond the fact that the weapon floats) it's up to DM discretion, but I expect most DMs would allow it (I would, mostly because it moves slowly enough that it's unlikely to matter much against most flying enemies).

That said, the Flaming Sphere spell does have specific rules about how large a gap or high a barrier it can jump, so it wouldn't be outside the bounds of possibility for a DM to rule that the Spiritual Weapon can't do that sort of thing because the spell isn't explicit about it.

Comment: True about the Flaming Sphere but it does not have a specific thing saying it is floating. It would show up on the ground and it can have it jump.  If I cast the sphere into the sky I would expect it to fall.  I am unsure if a spiritual weapon would fall or just stay up there. And since it floats and can move i was curious if it can it float up?

Comment: Yes, I understand perfectly what you're asking, and as far as I know there is no specific rule about that so you'll have to ask your DM. As I wrote in my answer there are justifications for both Yes and No answers. I'd personally answer Yes, but your DM would also be perfectly justified in saying No.

Comment: The lack of limitations similar to Flaming Sphere means there are no such limitations.

Comment: Sure, if you consider the text on Flaming Sphere to be limitations and not abilities. It's unclear to me.

Comment: This in fact just happened in a game I was playing in. Enemy casted flying spell and began to attack us from 60' in the air. THings looked bad for our small party. Ally cleric moves underneath and casts spiritual weapon. The weapon appears next to flying enemy, attacks, and hits. The flying caster fails concentration and falls for 6D6 more damage and dies. Encounter over.